# Render unicode from scope variable to HTML using currency filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to show the dynamic currency symbol in HTML.

```
<span> Amount : {{140 | currency:symbol}}</span>
```

In controller, I am having a `$scope` variable which has the currency Unicode.

```
$scope.symbol = '&#36;';
```

It is not rendering this (`&#36;`) unicode as ($) in HTML.

If I changed like,

```
<span> Amount : {{140 | currency:'&#36;'}}</span>
```

it's working fine. But I need to give the unicide from `$scope` variable.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

  app.controller('sample',function($scope){
    $scope.symbol = "&#36;";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="sample">
  <span> Amount : {{140 | currency:symbol}}</span> <br />
  
  <span> Amount : {{140 | currency:'&#36;'}}</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Marking as duplicated, since it would get solved by `ng-bind-html` directive with combination of inclusion of `ngSanitize` module

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar Please check the code snippet.

Comment: Here you check the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/swaVk9ggz0o8Guz6xHjL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar

Comment: Glad to help you on that :-)